# Is it possible to integrate Google Assistant with my custom app?

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

I would like to integrate Google assistant inside my app. The idea is that I have a app which provides various press services, like giving latest news and such. I would like to integrate Google assistant for handling some particular requests. For example the user may ask, "what did the Lakers yesterday?" If i search this on Google or ask to the assistant, i will get a card with the score of yesterday's game. I would like, from inside my app, to replicate this interaction, that is sending the request to Google assistant and showing the answer that Google return to the user (or at least opening Google assistant with the answer)

Is such a thing possible?

I was looking at Google Assistant service sdk (https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python/) and it says:

> The Google Assistant Service gives you full control over the integration with the Assistant by providing a streaming endpoint. Stream a user audio query to this endpoint to receive a Google Assistant audio response.

Is this possible only with audio interaction? I'm not quite certain this is the solution I should look into

Answer (score 0):

The Google Assistant SDK Service allows you to send both audio or text to the Assistant and you'll get back responses including audio, display text, and rich HTML visual content.

For mobile apps, there's less support compared to Python, but it's still doable. For example, there's a version of the SDK for [Android Things](https://github.com/androidthings/sample-googleassistant), which means for IoT devices like a Raspberry Pi. You can go through this project and remove all the IoT references, but it's something you'd need to do yourself.

Comment: I see. How does the "Register the Device Model" part fit into this tho? I mean, I don't have a specific target device on which to integrate the assistant, I have an app that can run on android smartphones

Comment: Device models are useful primarily for device actions, to associate an API call to a specific set of actions. This may be less important for your use-case.